# How to disable rounding in Decimal python?

Tags: python, decimal

When calculating, I get the wrong last digit of the number. At first, I just calculated with an accuracy of one digit more than I needed, and then I just removed the last rounded digit with a slice. But then I noticed that sometimes Decimal rounds more than one digit. Is it possible to calculate without rounding?

For example

```
from decimal import Decimal as dec, Context, setcontext, ROUND_DOWN
from math import log

def sqr(x):
    return x*x

def pi(n):
    getcontext().prec=n+1
    a=p=1
    b=dec(1)/dec(2).sqrt()
    t=dec(1)/dec(4)
    for _ in range(int(log(n,2))):
        an=(a+b)/2
        b=(a*b).sqrt()
        t-=p*sqr(a-an)
        p*=2
        a=an
    return sqr(a+b)/(4*t)
```

If I try pi (12) I get "3.141592653591" (the last 2 digits are wrong), but if I try pi(13), they both change to the correct ones - "3.1415926535899".

Comment: Provide your code.

Comment: Define "wrong last digit" here. And provide some examples of correct and incorrect rounding.

Comment: I didn't say that rounding was wrong, I said that I didn't need it.

Comment: You say multiple times that the last digit(s) are wrong; I take that to mean the rounding is (in your opinion) incorrect.

Comment: Note that, to the precision you show, the last digits should be `5898`, not `5899`.

Comment: It appears that you are claiming you get a better precision if you add one more iteration to the loop for your calculation of pi. That would make sense, and I don't see how that is a problem.

Comment: Both entering 12 and entering 13 I do 3 iterations. Only the precision I specify in getcontext().prec changes. That is, with the same number of iterations, I get these two different results, just by changing the accuracy. Two digits of the number change at once, and I do not know how to fix it. Rounding down doesn't solve this problem, I checked. I think the specifics of the task are such that rounding is not necessary here at all, so I asked if it could be disabled.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? That the final answer is precise to the precision `n` specified?

Comment: Yes, "n" is the desired number of decimal places, and because of the phenomenon I described, I get the wrong last digits, or risk getting them.

Comment: Why not perform the calculation with several extra digits, and then only round your return value to `n` digits?

Comment: After all, with squaring and square roots in a loop, you are going to lose precision. For example, consider `a = dec('9.51')`, then calculate `a.sqrt().sqr()`. For prec=1, you get 9, for prec=2, 9.6, for prec=3 you get 9.49. So you don't get the original value back in the last case, and the two other cases are not compatible with a rounded value of `a` itself (which would be 10 and 9.5, respectively).

Comment: At the very beginning, I did this (counting with one additional digit), and did not even round, but simply removed the last digit with a slice, but then I found that sometimes when rounding, two digits of the number change at once. I am not sure that if I cut off not one last digit, but two or more, it will solve my problem, because I do not know how many wrong digits I can get. What if there are more of them than the extra digits I took for calculations? I work with a large number of decimal places, so this is quite possible.

Comment: So, if I have it correct, your question then is: to how many digits of accuracy can I calculate π using this formula, given a certain, fixed, amount of accuracy for the starting and intermediate values?

Comment: No, my question is: is it possible to disable rounding in the decimal module, and if so, how? If rounding cannot be disabled, how can I prevent the phenomenon I described? Because I would like the function to return the number pi with as many correct digits as I specify.

Comment: How would you expect the decimal module to compute a square root without rounding?

Answer (score 0):

It's called [Roundoff Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) and is unavoidable when working with [Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). You can write the following code in your Python REPL and should get, interestingly, `False`.

```py
0.2 + 0.1 == 0.3 # False
```

It's because the last bits of float numbers are, actually, garbage. One way you can work around this is by using more terms in your series and, then, rounding the result to the wanted precision.

If you want to understand this deeper, you can read these two links I've attached and, maybe, some Numerical Computing textbook.

Comment: I am aware of this error.  But isn't the Decimal module needed to correct this inaccuracy?
    
    print(Decimal("0.1")+Decimal("0.2")) #0.3